# oracle sql regular expression to retrieve table names

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I having a table with one column of type varchar2(4000).  That column contains queries I want to retrieve table names by using regular expression.

EX:

```
 create table sam ( query_1 varchar2(4000));
```

Data is:

```
insert into sam values(
'select ename e, empno d , sal f,dname from emp e, dept d where e.deptno=d.deptno');
insert into sam values(
'SELECT B.DN,  A.DN , C.BN FROM A.DoG,   b.caT,  C.rAt')
```

How do I retrieve the table names from the query_1 column into another table?

Comment: If understood then u want to get the charcter 'emp' from `sam` ?

Comment: I think the OP wants emp, dept, dog, cat, rat -- all tables -- don't think it's possible.  Could perhaps write a stored proc, use a cursor and SUBSTR and INSTR, and possibly REGEX, but doubt it could be 100% accurate.

Comment: it depends on query to query....does your table consists of only insert statements which have the above pattern? 
i.e. from [{alias}].{tablename} [{alias}],[{alias}].{tablename} [{alias}]

Comment: I think we can retrive on basis of `from` key word which is always with table name

Answer (score 0):

This will get the job done for a single row, but does not work right when selecting multiple rows.  Perhaps someone a bit more skilled than me can improve on this:

```
select
  regexp_substr(c.split, '\S+') as table_name
from (
  select 
    regexp_substr(b.match, '[^,]+', 1, rownum) as split 
  from (
    select
      regexp_replace(regexp_substr(query_1, 'from.+?(where|group|order|$)', 1, 1, 'i'), '(from|where|group|order)', '', 1, 0, 'i') as match
    from
     sam
  )b
   connect by level <= length (regexp_replace (b.match, '[^,]+'))  + 1
) c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in straight-up Oracle SQL. You can't have dynamic table or column names. You will need to use PL/SQL and [Dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01101).